# Symfony and Doctrine Query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to return the ID 3 and 4 because is the latest value of each category.
How can i this?

```
    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $query->select('l');
    $query->groupBy('p.category');
    $query->orderBy('p.data', 'DESC');
```

With this code 1 and 2 are returned.

Sample Data:

```
ID | Name | Category | Data

1   |A      |1       |2014-01-01

2   |B      |2       |2014-01-01

3   |C      |1       |2014-01-03 

4   |D      |2       |2014-01-05
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');
$query->select('p, MAX(p.ID)');
$query->groupBy('p.category');
$query->orderBy('p.data', 'DESC')
```

here a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d66e/1) that prove correctness of the query

Answer (score -1):

Hello user3483478,

I think you are missing a simple factor here, try replacing 'l' with 'p' in your select statement. And set SQL LIMIT to 2, in Doctrine 2, it is 'setMaxResults', because you need to retrieve just 2 rows. This can be done easily and don't need to use a sub query.

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');
$query->select('p');
$query->groupBy('p.category');
$query->orderBy('p.data', 'DESC')
$query->setMaxResults(2);
```

Hope this helps,

Cheers!